# Animate class with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got one huge div containing multiple div classes. These classes are shown separately.

Now i'm trying to "swipe out" the current div class when clicking on another link. after complete the page has to be refreshed.

I've got the code that takes the url of the clicked btn.

```
<a href="#url" onclick='func(this)'>link1</a>
```

.

```
function func(elem) { //func = url from clicked element
    window.location.href = (elem.href);
    location.reload();
}
```

So i had the code below almost working but then i screwed up. 
the div class ="title" Could someone help me out?

Also, if not asked to much, i'd like to add a if-statement so that the code only executes if we're not on the url already. if(func !== func){}

```
function func(elem) {
    $('.title').animate({
            left: '-6000'
        }, // animating
        'slow',
        'swing', // the type of easing
        function () { // the callback
            window.location.href = (elem.href);
            location.reload();
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "almost working", and "screwed up"? What is currently happening?

Comment: Can you please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo

Comment: @Zhihao Well it is working if I apply this to the div id. But that's the main container and i'd like to animate what's inside it. 

the part of the onclick and that the script loads the href and reloads the page is working. 

So now I only want to apply a animation to, not the div id but the class. And I want the if-statement implanted so that nothing happens if func==func

Comment: Check my answer below, just eddited to fulfill your other request.

Comment: @Arash Why doesn't the current code work? Are you perhaps missing the `position: relative` styling on the `.title` elements?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IweXamiG/3/edit)**:

```
$('#urlGo').on('click', function(e){
 if(!window.location.href == $(this).attr('href')){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).css('position','relative').animate({
   left: -6000}, 
   'slow', 
   function () { // the callback
     window.location = $(this).attr('href');
      }
   ); 
  };//End if
});
```

Comment: Would like to note that a simple checking for equality between `window.location.href` and the `href` attribute will not always work. Links that differ between `http` and `https` will fail the check. If the link is to someone else on the same website, it could also fail because `href` could then be either an absolute or relative path, such as "/path/to/new/page". To solve this, you could either control the format of your `href` attributes, or use regex to "normalize" the strings.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But this should at least get @Arash started. he can tweak it if desired.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong or anything. Just pointing it out as a gotcha as I think it's worth noting. :)

Comment: Thanks, this should indeed get me started. I'll try out tonight, my eyes are hurting as hell atm :p 
I will mark it as solved when i got it figured out.

Comment: Arash, please let me know if u found my answer useful. Thanks.